# задний фон у пользовательского контрола wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Привет.Столкнулся с такой проблемой.Есть пользовательский контрол с заданным ControlTemplate

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="local:Tria">
                    <Border 
                        Name="CellBorder"
                        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5"
                        BorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="2">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Name="CellColor" Color="PaleVioletRed"/>
                        </Border.Background>
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Green"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
```

Так вот хочу поменять задний он программно

```
private void TriaClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
      (sender as Tria).Background = Brushes.Red;

    }
```

но он не меняет.

Comment: В свойстве `Background` задайте `TemplateBinding`. Выглядит это так: `Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"`

Comment: Вам помог вариант с `TemplateBinding`?

Comment: Тогда оформлю его как ответом )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В свойстве `ControlTemplate.Background` задайте `TemplateBinding`. В коде это выглядит так:

```
Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
```